# Example of malware in the wild?

Tags: malware, exploit

I'd like to test an application that detects malware on my network. In order to do that, I have a Windows VM set up that I'd like to infect with malware. But for the life of me, I can't seem to find an actual example of a website with malware in the wild.

To be clear -- what I'm looking for is a website that, when I navigate to it in my VM's web browser (any browser, I'm not picky), **automatically** installs malware (ideally invisibly) to the virtual disk. I realize that this probably requires an earlier patch of some plugin or software (e.g. Silverlight 4 or IE 8 or something) -- I don't mind this requirement.

Any suggestions on where to look for such a beast?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of websites that maintain and provide a list of malicious sources:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160729161440/http://www.selectrealsecurity.com/public-block-lists

Answer (score 2):

I guess I should preface this first with:  Please, please be careful.

A few sites you might check for indexing are:

- hxxp://www.blade-defender.org/eval-lab/
- hxxp://www.malware.lu/
- hxxp://www.offensivecomputing.net/
- hxxp://www.phishtank.com/